# Windows 11 file explorer scrolls to the very top if you copy or move any files in another window explorer instance

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11

I'm trying to manage files between two locations and I need the scroll location to stay in place so I can properly sort these files, but every time I copy or move a file anywhere, all open Windows Explorer windows scroll automatically to the top and I lose my place. It's intensely infuriating.

I saw unhelpful "advice" on Windows tech forums (per usual). Stuff like "it might be the mouse" or "update your system" or "open each explorer window as a new process" (I thought that last one might actually work, but alas...

Is there any way to fix this horrifying behavior?

Comment: I agree, windows 11 explorer is a mess, more so since they added tabs

Comment: When I use tabs (3 tabs and copy from tab2 to tab3) the scroll location (selected file in tab2) stays in place.  Did you try using tabs?  Consider a third party Explorer replacement.

Comment: Tabs wouldn't help because the point is to be able to drag and drop from one side/screen to the other.

Comment: @John any suggestions on an explorer replacement. I've seen some before that weren't great

Comment: I use xPlorer2 (zabkat) and it allows both adhoc changes to setup as well as a saved setup if you know what you need